# How Can I convert PlayFab's UserDataRecord to String array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, playfab

I was trying to get some variables from an specific player, and then store them in arrays to manipulate and display them, I don't have any problems putting the keys on the array, but at the moment of putting the values of the dictionary that returns for the get user data it doesn't let me store them in the array

It displays `Cannot convert from 'string[]' to ' PlayFabClientModels.UserDataRecord[]'`

```
private String[] qDataKeys;
private String[] qDataValues;

void GetQuestionsData()
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserData(new GetUserDataRequest()
    {
        PlayFabId = "someID",
        Keys = null
    }, 
    OnQuestionsDataReceived, 
    OnError
    );
    
}

void OnQuestionsDataReceived(GetUserDataResult result)
{

    result.Data.Keys.CopyTo(qDataKeys, 0);
    result.Data.Values.CopyTo(qDataValues, 0);// This is the one that gives the error, above one is okay
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is pretty clear in the error. The type returned from this call is of type `PlayFabClientModels.UserDataRecord[]`. Checking out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/playfab/client/player-data-management/getuserreadonlydata?view=playfab-rest#userdatarecord), the type UserDataRecord is setup as

```
Ordered by:
Data name
Data type
Data Description

LastUpdated 
string
Timestamp for when this data was last updated.

Permission  
UserDataPermission
Indicates whether this data can be read by all users (public) or only the user (private). This is used for GetUserData requests being made by one player about another player.

Value   
string
Data stored for the specified user data key.
```

I am assuming you would like the `Value` inside of the record. I am not sure how you are currently accessing the `Key` either as the docs specify that the `GetUserDataResult` returns `Data` which is of type `UserDataRecord` and `DataVersion` which is of type `number`.

The error is currently telling you that the `copyTo` you are using is failing because the current type is `PlayFabClientModels.UserDataRecord[]` and you are expecting `string[]`. You would need to iterate over each `UserDataRecord` and grab the `Value` data from each index.

I believe something along the lines of

`string[] yourData = result.Data.Value.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();`

Should work. You will need to include `using System.Linq` at the top of your file. If it does not work, I would just need to know the typing of `result.Data.Values` but due to the error, I am assuming it is an innumerable array of data. I am not familiar with PlayFab so if the current docs are outdated please correct me in the comments and I'll try to update the answer.

Comment: do the `....Select(x => x.Value)` has to be changed in any way?, in code it looks that is solved, but at the moment of running the method it says  `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: array`

Comment: When you mouse over the result.Data.Values, what type does it say that it is? The issue could be that some index in the list returned is null or that some index in the list of type Value is null.

Comment: It could also very well be that the entire list is null. I did not account for this. Try this `string[] yourData = result.Data.Values != null ? result.Data.Values.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray() : {};`

Comment: It looks that the code you gave me is right, but now there appeared two other problems, the key values were the ones that had that problem when building, the thing is that I want to get the Key and the Values, since the key should indicate what type of data I'm getting, do you think is there any way of getting the keys too?, it is going to be a long list of data and I need to obtain everything, that's why I'm trying to get it in this way and sort it into arrays...

Comment: ... , (the second problem is in here `questions = new String[qDataValues.Length, qDataValues.Length];` ) it tells me `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: The `Key` issue is part of my original post. When I looked at the docs I do not see how you are getting any data with Key. You are better off just pulling the entire `result.Data.Values` as the array, then iterating over that pulling whatever data you need. Looking at the docs again it doesn't seem like it defines the data type?

Comment: Like I said I have never used PlayFab. Can you tell me the specific data type that `GetUserDataResult` is? What data is has? The Docs tell me it only has a `Timestamp`, `Permission` and `Value`. There is no key.

Comment: I mean, for example for other things, I have another getUserData, and this one, contains this if `if (result.Data != null && result.Data.ContainsKey("A key")` and this is used to check if it exists a value with that name, I thought the result returned a dictionary because of that and that's why I've been doing it like that, and for example, to store one of the values you use `variable = result.Data["A key"].Value` but this is only for an specific value, and I need to get all of them that exists in a user

Comment: I think I'm gonna be putting the keys into the values, I figured out that the code you gave me in the answer works fine, and also with a Debug.Log it shows the data correctly, so I can just asign the first 4 characters on the values as a key and by there do what I wanted to do, you were very helpful and thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Glad you could get it working. Hope the rest of the PlayFab implementation goes smoothly!